# Spring Boot, Can't reach a different Controller Class

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security, thymeleaf

Request is always made to method(/login) in same Controller.
When you press Save button in Register.html, /login method in UserController.java class works automatically although it must run saveRegisterPage method (/registration/saveRegister) in RegisterController.java class.
What must be done in order to run saveRegisterPage method?

Thank you.

**UserController.java**

```
    @Controller
    public class UserController {
    
        @RequestMapping(value = "/register", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public String registerPage(Model model) {
            model.addAttribute("user", new User());
            return "register";
        }
        @RequestMapping("/")
        public String index() {
            return "login";
        }
    
        @RequestMapping("/login")
        public String login() {
            return "login";
        }
        
        @RequestMapping("/home")
        public String home() {
            return "home";
        }
    }
```

**RegisterController.java**

```
    @Controller
    @RequestMapping(value="/registration")
    public class RegisterController {
    
        @Autowired
        UserServiceImpl userServiceImpl;
    
        @RequestMapping(value = "/saveRegister", method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public String saveRegisterPage(@ModelAttribute("user") User user, BindingResult result, Model model, RedirectAttributes attributes) {
            model.addAttribute("user", user);
            if (result.hasErrors()) {
                return "register";
            } else {
                userServiceImpl.save(user);
            }
            return "home";
        }
    }
```

**home.html**

```
    <html>
    <head>...</head>
    <body>
    
    <div class="container">
        <h2>Welcome</h2>
        <a href="/logout" class="btn btn-danger">Logout</a>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**login.html**

```
    <html xmlns:th="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>...</head>
    <body>
    
    <div class="container">
        <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert" th:if="${param.error}">
            Wrong Username or Passrod
        </div>
        <form th:action="@{/login}" method="post">
            <h1 class="h3 mb-3 font-weight-normal">Signin</h1>
    
            <label>Username</label>
            <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control"/>
            <label>Password</label>
            <input type="password" id="password" name="password" class="form-control"/>
            <br/>
            <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">SignIn</button>
            <br/>
            <div class="margin-top20 text-center"><a th:href="@{/register}">Go Register</a>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**register.html**

```
    <html xmlns:th="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>....</head>
    <body>
    <div class="container">
        <form autocomplete="off" th:action="@{/registration/saveRegister}" th:object="${user}" method="post">
            <label>Name </label>
            <input type="text" id="firstName" placeholder="First Name" th:field="*{firstName}" 
    class="form-control"/><br/>
            <label>Last name </label>
            <input type="text" id="lastName" placeholder="First Name" th:field="*{lastName}" class="form-control"/><br/>
            <label>Email </label>
            <input type="text" id="email" placeholder="First Name" th:field="*{email}" class="form-control"/><br/>
            <label>Username</label>
            <input type="text" id="username" placeholder=" Username" th:field="*{username}" class="form-control"/><br/>
            <label>Password</label>
            <input type="text" id="password" placeholder=" Password" th:field="*{password}" class="form-control"/><br/>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success text-center form-control">Save</button>
        </form>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**SecurityConfiguration.java**

```
    @EnableWebSecurity
    public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{
    
        @Autowired
        private UserAuthService userAuthService;
    
        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.csrf().disable();
            http
                    .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/",  "/register", "/webjars/**", "/h2-console/**","/webjars/").permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
                    .and()
                    .formLogin().loginPage("/login").defaultSuccessUrl("/home", true).permitAll()
                    .and()
                    .logout()
                    .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
                    .logoutSuccessUrl("/home").permitAll()
                    .and()
                    .httpBasic();
            
            http.headers().frameOptions().disable();
    
        }
        
        @Override
        protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            auth.userDetailsService(userAuthService).passwordEncoder(encoder());
        }
        @Bean
        public PasswordEncoder encoder() {
            return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        }
    }
```

**pom.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        <parent>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.5</version>
            <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
        </parent>
        <groupId>com.zorogluresul.springexample1</groupId>
        <artifactId>springexample1</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <name>springexample1</name>
        <description>Spring Boot, Web, Thymeleaf, Jpa, Postgresql, Security</description>
        <properties>
            <java.version>11</java.version>
        </properties>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
                <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
                <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
                <scope>runtime</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
                <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.7-1</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
                <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.1-1</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </project>
```

Comment: I guess because u have defined <form th:action="@{/login}" method="post"> with @{/login}, therefore its automatically calling login api.

Comment: So What is your suggestion?

Comment: try this /registration/saveRegister

Comment: There is already /registration/saveRegister in registerPage.html @John

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add RegisterController's requestMapping `/registration` into antMatchers like this:

```
.antMatchers("/",  "/register", "/registration/*", "/webjars/**", "/h2-console/**","/webjars/").permitAll()
```

It contains `/*` at the end of the `/registration/*` in order to allow all requests in RegisterController. If you write it like `/registration/register`, it also runs saveRegisterPage method in RegisterController.

Comment: Thank you cafertayyar. Problem has been fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this Resul

```
import java.io.IOException; 
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping; 
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class UserController {

    @GetMapping("/register")
    public String registerPage(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("user", new Fragment3());
        return "register";
    }
    @GetMapping //main page
    public String index() {
        return "login";
    }
    @GetMapping("/login") //logging out from home
    public String logout() {
        return "login";
    }
    
    @PostMapping("/home")
    public String home() {
        return "home";
    }
}
---------------------------------------------------------------------------


import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping; 
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/registration")
public class RegisterController {

    @Autowired
    UserServiceImpl userServiceImpl;

    @PostMapping("/saveRegister")
    public String saveRegisterPage(@ModelAttribute("user") User user, BindingResult result, Model model, RedirectAttributes attributes) {
        model.addAttribute("user", user);
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            return "register";
        } else {
            userServiceImpl.save(user);
        }
        return "home";
    }
}`
```

most changes are at the backend
although do replace 2 lines in home.html for the logout.

```
<h2>Welcome</h2>
    <a  th:href="@{/login}" class="btn btn-danger">Logout</a>
```

Comment: Why did you change @{/logout} in home.html?
but Still, When pressing save in Register.html, it doesn't go to registration/save in RegisterController.java, it goes to /login in UserController.hava